# Change function Value from Android Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, cordova

I am an Android Developer and don't have any knowledge about JScript/Jquery/Phonegap etc. I found an example and I replace its web page with mine. In my web page I have an java script as follow:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">var map;function initialize()
{
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');


map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.0000,-79.5000),zoom: 13,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE});
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', addMarkers);}function addMarkers()
{
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(9.0000,-79.5000);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng,map: map});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I want to change Lat-Long value dynamically Using my android code. Please some one guide me to do this.

These is the android code to load html page on web view.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new NewsClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/map.html");
}

private class NewsClient extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        view.loadUrl("javascript:changeLocation('" + url + "')");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an example android application in which I use a test plugin as a gateway to send values from native code to Javascript plugin and update the DOM values.

[android-cordova-plugin](https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/tree/master/android-cordova-plugin)

If you are familiar with phonegap plugins then it would be easier to understand the code. I simply use following method in my Activity class to update the html side. Here `appcomm.updateValues()` is my gateway plugin method which received the values from native code without initiating any call from Javascript.

```
public void sendValue(String value1, String value2) {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        try {
            data.put("value1", value1);
            data.put("value2", value2);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("CommTest", e.getMessage());
        }
        String js = String.format("window.plugins.appcomm.updateValues('%s');",
                data.toString());
        this.sendJavascript(js);
    }
```